# Issue with convert NULL to String or to Double Issue

Tags: java, sql

I have a query that retrive an object type and convert it to double value. Here is how I did:

```
Double.valueOf(rs.getObject("price").toString()).doubleValue()));
```

However, if the price data in DB is NULL, I got error: NullPointerException.

How can I deal with it? If it is NULL, i want to just leave it blank.

I guess the issue is when it get null, Java cannot convert to string or to doubleValue(), How can I prevent this happen?

Comment: You cannot have a double or a string at the same time, unless your result type is `Object`

Comment: "i want to just leave it blank" There's no such thing as a "blank" `double`. If you really a `double` (rather than a `Double` or an `Object`), then [`NaN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) might be useful to you, or maybe `0`.

Comment: As an aside, what is the datatype of price in your db.  It might not be necessary to convert it at all.

Answer (score 1):

check `null`ity against `rs.getObject("price")` if you find it null then don't do above thing instead just leave it to the default value (blank or whatever) you want

Also handle `NumberFormatException` it could raise while converting `String` to `Double` if no proper value found

Comment: Thanks, I am take a look on that

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything with it, just check and make sure that it's not null -

```
Object obj = rs.getObject("price");
if(obj != null) {
     double doubleVal = Double.parseDouble(obj.toString());
else {
     //some default value or exception
}
```

---

In case the default is going to be 0 then you can just use [`ResultSet#getDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDouble%28java.lang.String%29) method.

> Returns:
>   the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value returned is 0